# Word/phrase that means "bad trend"?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Example sentence:

> People always ended up hating him. This __ not only manifested itself
>   in matters of friendship, also in his relationship with the opposite
>   sex.

The closest word I could think of was *incidence*, but it's not quite right for the context. Is there a better alternative?

Comment: 'Pattern' would work, though it is neutral rather than specifying that it's adverse. But i'm not sure that 'This', in your second sentence, isn't all you need.

Comment: Synonyms of _curse_, overlapping in the 'cause of misery' sense, include 
_affliction, blight, burden, scourge_ and _woe_.

Comment: I'm not clear what the trend is. Is it that each relationship trends downwards until it ends? Or is it that a succession of relationships point to a trend? *The inevitability* would work. *This eventuality* also works, as it piggybacks on the earlier sentence's *always* to gain the necessary sense of certain doom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*degradation*, *retrogression* or *regression* -

- [*degradation*](http://www.wordwebonline.com/search.pl?w=degradation):

  1. Changing to a lower state (a less respected state)

     - debasement
  2. A low or downcast state

     "each confession brought her into an attitude of degradation";

     - abasement, abjection
  3. (geology) the mechanical process of wearing or grinding something down (as by particles washing over it)

     - erosion, eroding, eating away, wearing, wearing away
- [*retrogression*](http://www.wordwebonline.com/search.pl?w=retrogression):

  1. Passing from a more complex to a simpler biological form

     - degeneration
  2. A return to an earlier state

     - regression, regress, reversion, retroversion
- [*regression*](http://www.wordwebonline.com/search.pl?w=regression):

  1. A return to an earlier state

     - regress, reversion, retrogression, retroversion
  2. An abnormal state in which development has stopped prematurely

     - arrested development, fixation, infantile fixation
  3. (psychiatry) a defence mechanism in which you flee from reality by assuming a more infantile state
  4. (statistics) the relation between selected values of x and observed values of y (from which the most probable value of y can be predicted for any value of x)

     - simple regression, regression toward the mean, statistical regression
  5. (programming) the reappearance of a software bug that has been fixed at least once before

-- WordWeb Online

Comment: None of these have the sense of *trend* as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 0):

"*Decay*" or *"inevitable decay"* could work here:

> People always ended up hating him. This **inevitable decay** not only manifested itself in matters of friendship, but also in his relationship with the opposite sex.